# How to write form_valid method in django correctly

Tags: django, forms, django-views

In my `views.py` I had a method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.fisher_id = self.request.user.fisher_id
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Then I changed my code to create Modal Window and save it. But I need to return in my code `super().form_valid(form)` because have problem with fisher DUPLICATE ERROR KEY.

My code now looks like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.fisher_id = self.request.user.fisher_id
    form.save()
    self.object = form.save()
    self.object.file.save('1.pdf', self.get_file())
    # return super().form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And I have a problem DUPLICATE ERRROR KEY without this comment string. How can I implement both this returns? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You're calling save twice which is likely an issue. If you wanted to set extra data on the instance created you can typically do something like this;

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False) # this validates the data and returns an object but doesn't save to the database
    obj.fisher_id = self.request.user.fisher_id
    obj.file.save('1.pdf', self.get_file())
    obj.save()
    self.object = obj
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```